# Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: question is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, html

I'm trying to make a quiz game for a school project and it's not doing its function (Like showing the answer options). And I've got the "Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: question is not defined".

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Spēle</title>
  <style>
        .box{
            max-width: 18rem;
            text-align: center;
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 8px;
            padding: 8px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container box">
      Spēle, "Kā sauc šo pilsētu?"
      <hr>
      <div id="question-title">
        Question title
      </div>
      <div id="option-list">
        <input type="radio" id="0" name="0"> option value</input>
      </div>
      <div id="score-area">
        Score Area
      </div><button id="submit">Iesniegt!</button><br>
      <button id="start">Sākt!</button><br>
      <button id="play-again">Spēlēt vēlreiz!</button>
    </div><!-- Database-->
    <script src="script.js"></script> 
    <script>


        // definē variantus:
        let questionNo = 0;
        let score = 0;
        let question_title = document.getElementById(question-title);
        let option_list = document.getElementById(option-list);
        let score_area = document.getElementById(score-area);
        let btn_submit = document.getElementById(submit);
        let start = document.getElementById(start);
        let play_again = document.getElementById(play-again);

        // paslepjam dažas lietas
        hideItems(question_title);
        hideItems(options_list);
        hideItems(btn_submit);
        hideItems(play_agian);
        hideItems(score_area);

        // Starta poga uz klikšķa
        start.addEventListener('click', function () {
            show(question_title);
            show(option_list);
            show(btn_submit);
            loadQuestions();
            hideItems(start);
        });

        function loadQuestions() {
            // parbaudi vai ir jautājami jautājumi
            if (questionNo < data.lengt) {
                let q = data[questionNo].qs;
                let optionsArray = data[questionNo].options;

                // Parādīt jautājumus:
                question_title.innerText = q;

                // Parādīt opcijas:
               option_list.innerText = "";
                for (let i =0; i < 4; i++) {
                    option_list.innerHTML = options_list.innerHTML +
                    `
                    <input type="radio" id="${i}" name="${question_title}">${optionsArray[i]}</input>
                    `;
                }
            }else{
              console.log("no more question")

              show(score_area);
              score_area.innerText = "Pareizās atbildes: " + score;

              hideItems(btn_submit);
              show(play_again);
            }
        }

        play_again.addEventListener("click", function() {
            location.reload();
        })

        btn_submit.addEventListener('click', function () {
          let id = getCheckedId();

          try {
              if (id == data[questionNo].answerId) {
                  score++;
                  console.log("correct answer")
              }
          } catch (error) {

          }
          
          questionNo++;

          loadQuestions();
        })

        function getCheckedId() {
            for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (document.getElementById(i).checked)
                    console.log("you selected:"+ i)
                    return i;
        }}

        function hideItems(element) {
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
        function showItems(element) {
            element.style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Script.js**

```
 var data= [
    {
        "qs": "1. Pilsēta",
        "options": [
            "Rīga",
            "Kuldīga",
            "Jēkabpils",
            "Talsi"
        ],
        "answerId": 2
    },
    {
        "qs": "2. Pilsēta",
        "options": [
            "Ogre",
            "Liepāja",
            "Snēpele",
            "Daugavpils"
        ],
        "answerId": 1
    },
    {
        "qs": "3. Pilsēta",
        "options": [
            "Tukums",
            "Grobiņa",
            "Cēsis",
            "Priekule"
        ],
        "answerId": 4
    },
    {
        "qs": "4. Pilsēta",
        "options": [
            "Basi",
            "Ezere",
            "Saldus",
            "Turlava"
        ],
        "answerId": 3
    },
    {
        "qs": "5. Pilsēta",
        "options": [
            "Kandava",
            "Valmiera",
            "Rūjiena",
            "Krāslava"
        ],
    }
]
```

I tried to make a quiz game with images (For cities like "Whats the city called" from the image and there's four options on which one is the correct city.) but sort of failed because its not doing its thing and I am a beginner at coding. It was supposed to show u a picture of a city and you have to check the correct answer. Once you've submitted the answer you receive another question and so on until you've answered all of the questions and it shows your score and gives you a option to "play again".

Comment: I can't find any reference to a variable called `question` (using browser search). Which line is the error referring to?

Comment: Re: `document.getElementById(question-title)` is incorrect. The parameter is being evaluated as `question - title` and throwing the error. `getElementById` takes a string, e.g., `"question-title"`.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it? Cause as I said I am a beginner and don't know much. It also isn't specifically showing where the error is since it's showing in debug console (I'm using Visual Studio Code)

Comment: Make it a string.

Comment: How exactly you do that?

Comment: Put quotes around it as I did in my first comment.

Comment: Oh alright but wouldn't I have to string the others aswell? Like

``` let option_list = document.getElementById("option-list");
        let score_area = document.getElementById("score-area");
        let btn_submit = document.getElementById("submit");
        let start = document.getElementById("start");
        let play_again = document.getElementById("play-again"); ```

Comment: Yes, you would.

Comment: Okay so what I did is put them in ' ' and it  sort of fixed it now it's giving me another error " Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') " at hideItems

Comment: Check your spelling for the remaining errors (make sure you're using the correct variable names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### document.getElementById() is not receiving a string as parameter

I think that you should have used quotation marks "" in the parameter

```
let question_title = document.getElementById("question-title");
let option_list = document.getElementById("option-list");
let score_area = document.getElementById("score-area");
let btn_submit = document.getElementById("submit");
let start = document.getElementById("start");
let play_again = document.getElementById("play-again");
```

So it can recognizes the value as a string and finds the element using its ID, since there is no quotation marks "", it is trying to find a variable named ***question*** that does not exists so a error is returned saying this variable is not defined.

Also, it is not trying to find a variable named ***question-title*** because the minus character ***-*** is invalid for variable names.

### The funcion is defined as *showItems* and being used jus as *show*

You are defining the function as ***showItems()***

```
function showItems(element) {
    element.style.display = "block";
}
```

but you are always calling it as ***show()***

```
show(question_title);
show(option_list);
show(btn_submit);
```

you should call it using ***showItems()***

```
showItems(question_title);
showItems(option_list);
showItems(btn_submit);
```

### Variable option_list being used as options_list with an s

You should remove the s in theses lines

```
hideItems(options_list);

option_list.innerHTML = options_list.innerHTML +
`
<input type="radio" id="${i}" name="${question_title}">${optionsArray[i]}</input>
`;
```

### Variable play_again being used as play_agian

You should write it correctly

```
hideItems(play_agian);
```

### Atribute .length being called as .lengt

You should write it correctly

```
if (questionNo < data.lengt)
```

### Functions needs to go before using them

So you should write it in the beginning of the script, so the program knows what is it and how it works when you call

```
<script>

    function getCheckedId() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById(i).checked)
                console.log("you selected:"+ i)
                    return i;
            }}

    function hideItems(element) {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
    function showItems(element) {
        element.style.display = "block";
    }
```

### The complete and corrected code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Spēle</title>
  <style>
        .box{
            max-width: 18rem;
            text-align: center;
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 8px;
            padding: 8px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container box">
      Spēle, "Kā sauc šo pilsētu?"
      <hr>
      <div id="question-title">
        Question title
      </div>
      <div id="option-list">
        <input type="radio" id="0" name="0"> option value</input>
      </div>
      <div id="score-area">
        Score Area
      </div><button id="submit">Iesniegt!</button><br>
      <button id="start">Sākt!</button><br>
      <button id="play-again">Spēlēt vēlreiz!</button>
    </div><!-- Database-->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>

        // Functions needs to go before using them
        function getCheckedId() {
            for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (document.getElementById(i).checked)
                    console.log("you selected:"+ i)
                    return i;
        }}

        function hideItems(element) {
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
        function showItems(element) {
            element.style.display = "block";
        }

        // definē variantus:
        let questionNo = 0;
        let score = 0;
        let question_title = document.getElementById("question-title");
        let option_list = document.getElementById("option-list");
        let score_area = document.getElementById("score-area");
        let btn_submit = document.getElementById("submit");
        let start = document.getElementById("start");
        let play_again = document.getElementById("play-again");

        // paslepjam dažas lietas
        hideItems(question_title);
        hideItems(option_list);
        hideItems(btn_submit);
        hideItems(play_again);
        hideItems(score_area);

        // Starta poga uz klikšķa
        start.addEventListener('click', function () {
            showItems(question_title);
            showItems(option_list);
            showItems(btn_submit);
            loadQuestions();
            hideItems(start);
        });

        function loadQuestions() {
            // parbaudi vai ir jautājami jautājumi
            if (questionNo < data.length) {
                let q = data[questionNo].qs;
                let optionsArray = data[questionNo].options;

                // Parādīt jautājumus:
                question_title.innerText = q;

                // Parādīt opcijas:
               option_list.innerText = "";
                for (let i =0; i < 4; i++) {
                    option_list.innerHTML = option_list.innerHTML +
                    `
                    <input type="radio" id="${i}" name="${question_title}">${optionsArray[i]}</input>
                    `;
                }
            }else{
              console.log("no more question")

              showItems(score_area);
              score_area.innerText = "Pareizās atbildes: " + score;

              hideItems(btn_submit);
              showItems(play_again);
            }
        }

        play_again.addEventListener("click", function() {
            location.reload();
        })

        btn_submit.addEventListener('click', function () {
          let id = getCheckedId();

          try {
              if (id == data[questionNo].answerId) {
                  score++;
                  console.log("correct answer")
              }
          } catch (error) {

          }

          questionNo++;

          loadQuestions();
        })
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that did help with that and my mistake didn't notice that. Its the small things that r hard to notice.
Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: show is not defined when I try to launch it in debug mode and test it out

Comment: I have edited the comment and added the revision for the new problem you commented.

Comment: Do you happen to have discord? Because I'm not getting any errors or anything BUT it isn't functioning correctly and would love to chat about that there.
EDIT: It's automatically jumping to
 else{
              console.log("no more question")

              showItems(score_area);
              score_area.innerText = "Pareizās atbildes: " + score;

              hideItems(btn_submit);
              showItems(play_again);
            }

Comment: I have set your code in my computer and tested it and with the help of ChatGPT I've found another errors that I edited the comment and written the solutions. If you still need further assist send me your discord and I would be glad to help. I'm just not sure if I'm gonna be able to help you now.

Comment: Alright, I noticed it still doesn't let me go further with the questions. My discord is Tox1city#6965 and Ive also followed you on instagram

Comment: Okay so, my questions are not getting checked and it says: Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked'). Would be nice if someone could help me and possibly add my discord Tox1city#6965